# How do I find the value of a node in the next level down?

Tags: c#, xml

So I currently have a XML Node at the Item level:

```
    <Item>
        <Item_Number>0000000063089</Item_Number>
        <English_Description>MOUNTAIN DEW</English_Description>
        <French_Description>MOUNTAIN DEW</French_Description>
        <Price>219</Price>
        <Department>000006</Department>
        <Department_Description>BEVERAGES</Department_Description>
        <FHST>11</FHST>
        <HST>18</HST>
        <UPC>0006900005056</UPC>
        <Total_Without_Tax>219</Total_Without_Tax>
        <Total_With_Tax>248</Total_With_Tax>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Item>
```

How do I get say the Item_Number value, which is 0000000063089 for that Node only?  In C#.

The node is stored as this:

```
     XmlNode node;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[]`:

```
node["Item_Number"].InnerText == "0000000063089"
```

Or `SelectSingleNode()`:

```
node.SelectSingleNode("Item_Number").InnerText == "0000000063089"
```

The latter uses namespaces, and the former does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Display the contents of the child nodes.
if (node.HasChildNodes)
{
  for (int i=0; i<node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
  }
}
```

So if you wanted the first item then it would just be node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText

Answer (score 0):

Not that there is anything wrong with the answers you have already gotten but you could also use Linq to do it.  Something like:

```
node.ChildNodes
    .OfType<XmlNode>()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Item_Number")
    .Select(x=>x.InnerText).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the documentation for the XmlNode class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx There's probably a property or method to do what you want to do.